# Any mobile ad platform that allow AJAX requests?

Tags: admob, google-ads-api, ads

I've uploaded an HTML5 ad to my AdMob account, but it's disapproved because I have included JS code that makes ajax get requests to my website (I guess it's the reason because the same html was approved after removing the AJAX requests).

Do you know any limitations on AJAX requests in AdWords? Can you suggest some documentation on the issue? Any alternative platform that approves ads with AJAX request?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this thread could help you:
[AdWords Conversion code with Google Tag manager for Ajax and self-submit forms](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Articles/AdWords-Conversion-code-with-Google-Tag-manager-for-Ajax-and/ba-p/268469)

**Step 1**: Log in to your google tag manager account, if you don’t have one just create one using your gmail / Adwords logins.

**Step 2**: Create a container and place it on all pages of your website

**Step 3**: Create a new tag in Google Tag Manager name it as “Event Listener for contact form submit” (I am naming this for contact form submit you can name it according to your objective)
[image]

**Step 4**: Choose tag type as Event >> Form Submit Listener

[image]
**Step 5**: Set a rule for this event listener tag to fire on page where you form is located

[image]

**Step 6**: Select “Wait for tags” and “check validation” options and save this tag (Maximum wait is 2 seconds)

[image]

**Step 7**: Create one more tag call it “Adwords conversion tracking” and in tag type select “Adwords conversion tracking”
[image]

Step 8: Set a rule for this tag to fire
{{event}} equals : gtm.formSubmit

{{url}} contains : contact.php (your form page)

[image]

**Step 9**: Create a new version of your container

[image]

**Step 10**: Click on Update , preview & Debug

[image]

**Testing:**

**Step 11**: Visit your form page in the same browser and take a look at debug window at the bottom of the browser
It should show event listener tag firing but conversion tag not firing

[image]

**Step 12**: Submit the form
Keep watching your debugger at bottom

As soon as you submit Adwords conversion tracking should say Fired on event “gtm.formSubmit”.

This means everything has worked and you are ready to go live

In your google tag manager navigate to versions >> overview >> version # which you created and click on Publish

[image]

Comment: I can't understand how this article helps me to upload html ads with ajax requests. It seems like they talk about conversion tracking, while I just need to make a simple AJAX request within my AD html